# Unable to change the visibility of a button link

Tags: c#, asp.net

The Control.Visible property can change the visibility of a button to true or false. But for some reason, it doesn't work when I try to change the visibility to false..

```
 if (Session["UserGroup"] == "Group2")
      {
           someLink.Visible = false;
      }
```

The someLink is initially set to true. But it remains true despite a user from the "Group2" usergroup logging in.

I don't think it has to do with my sql connection because it properly displays that user's name using this

```
 userNameLabel.Text = "Logged in as ";
 userNameLabel.Text += Session["Fname"] + " " + Session["Lname"];
```

As for storing the session, this is what I have

```
 Session["UserName"] = dr[0].ToString();
 Session["Fname"] = dr[1].ToString();
 Session["Lname"] = dr[2].ToString();
 Session["UserGroup"] = dr[3].ToString();
 ...
```

Comment: You sure, Session["UserGroup"] value is "Group2", but not "Group2   " (with some trailing spaces) (I have seen SQL Server returning data like that) or may be a lower/upper case different, you might want to check that!

Comment: What do you mean by - "it doesn't work"? does it step into this line - `someLink.Visible = false;` try comparing it with ordinal, ignore case comparison as well

Comment: "it doesn't work" means that button is still visible when a user from the Group2 logs in. @sthotakura: I've changed "Group2" to "Group2 " as well as "group2" to "group2 " but that doesn't seem to do it either.

Comment: Did you try debugging the app? and When you debug the app, does the code within the if block execute?

Comment: Yeah the code doesn't execute. It now says "Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'. Which I've already done

Comment: Have you tried `if (Session["UserGroup"].ToString() == "Group2")` ?

Comment: @JamesW. Does it work after you casting the left hand side to 'string'?

Comment: You are trying to compare an object to string. Try [Yuriy Galanter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/961695/yuriy-galanter)'s solution.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter that worked. But I thought I had already converted it to a string by assigning it to the datareader .ToString part..?

Comment: When you put anything in Session, it is converted to object. So, when getting from Session, you always need to cast it back to respected type.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that your code is failing at this point `if (Session["UserGroup"] == "Group2")`. Session["UserGroup"] needs to be cast as a string.

```
string usergroup = (string)Session["UserGroup"];

if (usergroup == "Group2"){
    someLink.Visible = false;
}
```

This should work. I haven't tested this though.